# Visual Studio Code auto completion shows a lot of options

Tags: typescript, intellisense, visual-studio-code

VS Code shows a lot of extra options in the suggestions list other than the known type. Screenshots are below.

Is it possible to narrow the options down to the type itself or at least show them at the top in VS Code?

For the type `{a: string, b: number}`

**VS Code**: *they are in the middle of the huge suggestion list.*
[image]

**IntelliJ IDE (Rider/WebStorm):** Concise list.
[image]

Comment: For me they are shown at the top. (vscode v1.32.3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The completion items you're seeing there are [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) (indicated by their icon), likely contributed by the built-in TypeScript extension. You can use the `"editor.snippetSuggestions"` setting to control how (or if) snippets are presented:

- `"top"` - Show snippet suggestions on top of other suggestions.
- `"bottom"` - Show snippet suggestions below other suggestions.
- `"inline"` - Show snippet suggestions with other suggestions. (default)
- `"none"` - Do not show snippet suggestions.

Comment: You're very fast :) I just found out that was the issue, that setting somehow got into the settings.json file and after commenting that out it started to work! Thanks a lot for clarifying it was working for you as expected, that gave me a good clue. I will accept your post as the answer.

Comment: It actually wasn't me who left that "working for me" comment, but glad to have helped anyway. :)

Comment: Oh yeah, at 1am on Monday night my mind was playing tricks :-) Still it worked and gave me a good peace of mind to sleep.

Comment: I used the option "bottom", and the properties of the objects appeared first in the list, it was very good, thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

After @zerkms's comment I disabled all extensions and commented out all settings in my workspace and IDE's settings.json files, then found that this setting, somehow got in there, was causing that issue.

`"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",`

After removing that I got this:

[image]